# Property 'DATCRE' does not exist

Tags: angular

I created an interface with multiple properties.

```
export interface StandingResponse extends ApiResponse {
    ORD_CLI: StandingOrderPortfolio[];
}

export interface StandingOrderPortfolio {
    DEPO: number;
    INTITULE1: string;
    PHONE: string;
    ORDDETAIL: {
      DATCRE: string;
      TITRE: {
        ISIN: string;
      }[];
    }[];
  }
```

I copied the JSON below, is it correct please?

```
{

   "ORD_CLI":[
      {
         "DEPO":123248626491,
         "INTITULE1":"PORTEFEUILLE TB58",
         "PHONE":"00",
         "ORDDETAIL":[
            {
               "DATCRE":"2022-03-31",
               "TITRE":{
                  "ISIN":"BE0947764743",
               },
            }
         ]
      }
   ],

}
```

I display `DEPO`, `INTITULE1`, `PHONE` without any problem. Now I would like to display `DATCRE` and `ISIN`.

In the HTML template, how can I add DATECRE and ISIN? I'm lost in the iterations?

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let standingOrders of standingResponse.ORD_CLI">
   <tr *ngFor="let standingOrder of standingOrders.ORDDETAIL">
      <td class="text-center">{{standingOrders.DEPO | accountDash}}</td>
      <td>{{standingOrders.INTITULE1}}</td>
      <td>{{standingOrders.PHONE}}</td>
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since you have iterated the `standingOrders.ORDDETAIL` array with *ngFor, what you need is `{{ standingOrder.DATCRE }}`. Make sure that you place it in the inner element of `<tr *ngFor="let standingOrder of standingOrders.ORDDETAIL">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`standingOrders.ORDDETAIL` is an array. You are in the correct direction which you have done to iterate the `standingOrders.ORDDETAIL` array with `*ngFor`.

Within the `<tr>` element, you just need to access `DATECRE` with `standingOrder.DATCRE`. For `ISIN`, you should access with `standingOrder.TITRE.ISIN`.

Your HTML structure should be looked as below:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let standingOrders of standingResponse.ORD_CLI">
  <tr *ngFor="let standingOrder of standingOrders.ORDDETAIL">
    ...

    <td>{{ standingOrder.DATCRE }}</td>
    <td>{{ standingOrder.TITRE.ISIN }}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```